# Method 'unsafeBitCast' crash when use CoreText's CTRunDelegate

Tags: ios, swift3

Following is the code when use CoreText

Break on the last line ***'unsafeBitCast(...)'***,

Console log 'fatal error: ***'can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes'***

```
  let str = " 2"

  let mutableAttrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)

        var callBack = CTRunDelegateCallbacks(version: kCTRunDelegateVersion1, dealloc:

 { (obj) in

    }, getAscent: { (obj) -> CGFloat in
        return 40
    }, getDescent: { (obj) -> CGFloat in
        return 30
    }) { (obj) -> CGFloat in
        return 20
    }
    var imgUrl = "http://img3.3lian.com/2013/c2/64/d/65.jpg"
    let callDelegate = CTRunDelegateCreate(&callBack,&imgUrl)
    mutableAttrStr.addAttribute(kCTRunDelegateAttributeName as String, value: callDelegate!, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: 1))
        ...
        ...

        ...
    let attributes = CTRunGetAttributes(run as! CTRun) as NSDictionary

    let delegate = attributes.value(forKey: kCTRunDelegateAttributeName as String)

    let imgPointer =  CTRunDelegateGetRefCon(delegate as! CTRunDelegate)

    let urlStr:String = unsafeBitCast(imgPointer, to: String.self);
```

***imgPointer*** is actual UnsafeMutableRawPointer type ,but I have to convert it to String to tell the compiler

If I do like this :

```
 let imgPointer =  CTRunDelegateGetRefCon(delegate as! CTRunDelegate) as! String
```

Unfortunately ,compiler warning :

[image]

Any help are appreciate!

Comment: `imgPointer` isn't a `String`, it's a pointer to a string.  You can access the string it is pointing to by doing `let urlStr = imgPointer.load(as: String.self)`

Comment: @dan Can you tell me what is the difference between  `imgPointer.load(as: String.self)` and `unsafeBitCast(imgPointer, to: String.self) ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @dan , used method `'let urlStr = imgPointer.load(as: String.self)'` replace `'let urlStr:String = unsafeBitCast(imgPointer, to: String.self)'`solved the problem.